# Android market filter Google API Level

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm developing an application that use `MapView`, `MapActivity`, so i nedd to add the google api library in my manifest and so on.

I'm using Eclipse IDE and when i start my application on my HTC Desire, Eclipse advise me that the device is not compatible for my application.

I give you some details:

My `minSdkVersion` in the manifest file is 4 (1.6), and my device is running a 2.3.7 version of Android.
I've already developed a few apps that don't use google's api, and everything went as expected.

So, why Eclipse is saying this? Is for the Google's Api library?

If i will deploy my app to the play store, will it be visible? For what devices?

Thanks.

Comment: "Eclipse advise me that the device is not compatible for my application" -- where and how, precisely, does it do this? "Is for the Google's Api library?" -- is your HTC Desire running the original ROM from HTC, or did you install some replacement ROM? Also, please consider editing your question and posting your manifest, in case we see any problems in there.

Comment: My HTC is not running the original rom. Yes it could be. Thank you. But how does the playstore filter applicazioni which use google api? Does it refer only for the min sdk version? I will post my manifest later. Btw Eclipse shows me the choose of the device when i try to run, which means that my device is not compatible. By default it runs on compatible devices without asking for a choose.

Comment: "Does it refer only for the min sdk version?" -- no, it is based on the `<uses-library>` element. Devices lacking that firmware library will not be able to install your app.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was missing. But, how many mobile devices have not any google api libraries?

Comment: Pretty much every device that legitimately has the Play Store on it will have the Maps SDK add-on.